# Bellman Ford Display predecessor for every iterations

Tags: java

Here the predecessor vertices get displayed for all iterations. I want the final predecessor to be displayed for the vertices

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class BellmanFord {
    LinkedList<Edge> edges;
    int d[];
    int n,e,s;
    final int INFINITY=999;
    private static class Edge  {
        int u,v,w;
        public Edge(int a, int b, int c){
            u=a;
            v=b;
            w=c;
       }
       BellmanFord() throws IOException{
            int item;
            edges=new LinkedList<Edge>();
            BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter number of vertices ");
            n=Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
            System.out.println("Cost Matrix");
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                item=Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
                if(item!=0)
                    edges.add(new Edge(i,j,item));
            }
            e=edges.size();
            d=new int[n];
            System.out.print("Enter the source vertex ");
            s=Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
       }
       void relax() {
            int i,j;
            for(i=0;i<n;++i)
                d[i]=INFINITY;;
            d[s] = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
                 for (j = 0; j < e; ++j)
                     if (d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w < d[edges.get(j).v])
                     {                         
                         d[edges.get(j).v] = d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w;
                        /*Gives me the predecessor nodes of all iterations How can i get the final predecessornodes*/                                                                                                     System.out.println(edges.get(j).v+" Has predecessor " + edges.get(j).u);
                     }
        }
        boolean cycle() {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < e; ++j)
                if (d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w < d[edges.get(j).v])
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException   {
             BellmanFord r=new BellmanFord();
             r.relax();
             if(r.cycle())
             for(int i=0;i<r.n;i++)
             System.out.println(r.s+"to"+i+" ==> "+r.d[i]);
             else
             System.out.println(" There is a nagative edge cycle ");
       }
}
```

The erronous output is as follows. I am trying to print out the predecessor for every iterations:

```
**OUTPUT:**

Enter number of vertices
Cost Matrix
0
-1
4
0
0
0
0
3
2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
5
0
0
0
0
0
-3
0
Enter the source vertex
1 Has predecessor 0
2 Has predecessor 0
2 Has predecessor 1
3 Has predecessor 1
4 Has predecessor 1
3 Has predecessor 4
0to0 ==> 0
0to1 ==> -1
0to2 ==> 2
0to3 ==> -2
0to4 ==> 1
```

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: you didn't ask a question ha?

Comment: now i did sorry . Its like predecessor nodes get displayed for all iterations i just want the final predecessor nodes to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your last lines are very less understandable and so I give you my program which I made a few days back.. you can look for the mistake your program makes since its difficult to understand 100 lines of code and find out errors :
Also I advice you to focus more on writing neat and commented codes rather than straightaway focussing on time optimizations. Only check the logic and try to implement it in your code ,that's why I didn't post a Java code so that you could get everything easily :)

```
// A C / C++ program for Bellman-Ford's single source shortest path algorithm.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

// a structure to represent a weighted edge in graph
struct Edge
{
    int src, dest, weight;
};

// a structure to represent a connected, directed and weighted graph
struct Graph
{
    // V-> Number of vertices, E-> Number of edges
    int V, E;

    // graph is represented as an array of edges.
    struct Edge* edge;
};

// Creates a graph with V vertices and E edges
struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc( sizeof(struct Graph) );
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;

    graph->edge = (struct Edge*) malloc( graph->E * sizeof( struct Edge ) );

    return graph;
}

// A utility function used to print the solution
void printArr(int dist[], int n)
{
    printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
}

// The main function that finds shortest distances from src to all other
// vertices using Bellman-Ford algorithm.  The function also detects negative
// weight cycle
void BellmanFord(struct Graph* graph, int src)
{
    int V = graph->V;
    int E = graph->E;
    int dist[V];

    // Step 1: Initialize distances from src to all other vertices as INFINITE
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        dist[i]   = INT_MAX;
    dist[src] = 0;

    // Step 2: Relax all edges |V| - 1 times. A simple shortest path from src
    // to any other vertex can have at-most |V| - 1 edges
    for (int i = 1; i <= V-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < E; j++)
        {
            int u = graph->edge[j].src;
            int v = graph->edge[j].dest;
            int weight = graph->edge[j].weight;
            if (dist[u] + weight < dist[v])
                dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;
        }
    }

    // Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles.  The above step guarantees
    // shortest distances if graph doesn't contain negative weight cycle.  
    // If we get a shorter path, then there is a cycle.
    for (int i = 0; i < E; i++)
    {
        int u = graph->edge[i].src;
        int v = graph->edge[i].dest;
        int weight = graph->edge[i].weight;
        if (dist[u] + weight < dist[v])
            printf("Graph contains negative weight cycle");
    }

    printArr(dist, V);

    return;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{

    int V = 5;  // Number of vertices in graph
    int E = 8;  // Number of edges in graph
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V, E);

    // add edge 0-1 
    graph->edge[0].src = 0;
    graph->edge[0].dest = 1;
    graph->edge[0].weight = -1;

    // add edge 0-2 
    graph->edge[1].src = 0;
    graph->edge[1].dest = 2;
    graph->edge[1].weight = 4;

    // add edge 1-2 
    graph->edge[2].src = 1;
    graph->edge[2].dest = 2;
    graph->edge[2].weight = 3;

    // add edge 1-3 
    graph->edge[3].src = 1;
    graph->edge[3].dest = 3;
    graph->edge[3].weight = 2;

    // add edge 1-4 
    graph->edge[4].src = 1;
    graph->edge[4].dest = 4;
    graph->edge[4].weight = 2;

    // add edge 3-2 
    graph->edge[5].src = 3;
    graph->edge[5].dest = 2;
    graph->edge[5].weight = 5;

    // add edge 3-1 
    graph->edge[6].src = 3;
    graph->edge[6].dest = 1;
    graph->edge[6].weight = 1;

    // add edge 4-3 
    graph->edge[7].src = 4;
    graph->edge[7].dest = 3;
    graph->edge[7].weight = -3;

    BellmanFord(graph, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kavish. But i want in Java

Comment: I told you the code is pretty well understandable . I have written the steps . You don't have to change your code all over again . Only check for the errors in your code yourselves .I have already written the steps in comments . you can read it and do the same in java yourself.

Comment: i have mentioned comments in my program.That should help